# Google Sheets - Count >0 in a table, with column and row matching/criteria

Tags: google-sheets

Maybe I am having a block, but is there any way to count the following:

I have a table with Fruits/Type and monthly sales.

[Google Sheets Here:](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12f_-hg-8gD_qFQnDHvlFPDMenf6k3Rl-g-mzD4GsX04/edit#gid=2100307022)

I can SUM the sales for the criteria (dropdown) with:

```
=sumproduct( if( regexmatch( A2:A11, G1)* regexmatch( B2:B11,H1) * regexmatch( C1:E1,I1), C2:E11, "") )
```

Which will sum the number of Apples, Natural, in Jan.

Can I count how many times was sold? B17 should be 2 and B18 should be 4

I tried several ways, even with simpler formulas, but now I am confused.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: `DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question.` Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[You may test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12f_-hg-8gD_qFQnDHvlFPDMenf6k3Rl-g-mzD4GsX04/edit#gid=1393047315):*

```js
=counta(ifna(filter(filter(C:E,if(I1="",C1:E1=C1:E1,C1:E1=I1)),if(G1="",1,A:A=G1)*(if(H1="",1,B:B=H1)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! it worked! Learned something new today!